# restrict duplicate entry,iphone

Tags: iphone

HI All,

i am inserting , say name to sqlite, than showing it on tableview.

But i want say restrict user to insert duplicate name.

for first time  data gets inserted perfectly, but when i insert it on second time, it again get inserted, thats what i want to prevent.

HOw can i check if the value 'name' already exist in sqlite and show alert to tell user that this value already exist.

edited

i have an array abc , having few values., values in array i am adding from another view, now say if abc contains value "a1", now if i again inserting "a1", it should not except "a1", in a way how i can restrict an array to add duplicate value.

regards

Comment: I forget the exact SQL syntax, but you need to and a "CONFLICT" clause to your SQL insert statement.

Comment: i hv an idea if i give the feild a "unique" property in sqlite, it wont allow to enter the same value again.but i dont knw how to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

Use unique constraint in your SQL database.  [Here's a link](http://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_unique.asp) with some basics on it.  Here's some specifics on how to create table with unique contraints with [SQLite](http://zetcode.com/databases/sqlitetutorial/constraints/).

To alert users, just capture the error message from your SQL query and then output as needed.

Edited (for new question):

Easiest way is to parse through the array and do duplicate checks.  There's logic out there for faster searching but if you have a small array, then all you really need is a for loop that iterates through each array element and checks that the new value you are adding is not already there.